# Can't stop iframe from loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, iframe

So, I am patching a really crowded web radio player and sadly everything has to be patched in production mode.

```
<div class="hidden_element" id="hideflash">
    <iframe frameBorder="0" width="315" height="45" id="flash" scrolling="no" src="THESOURCE"></iframe>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var firefox = /Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    if (Modernizr.flash && !firefox) {
        // Supports Flash and is not Firefox
        $("#html5").addClass("is-splash");
        $("#html5").addClass("is-paused");
        $('video').removeAttr("autoplay");
        $("#seekbar").hide();
        $("#html5").hide();
    } 
    if (firefox) {
        // Firefox Detected- Normal HTML5 Initiation
        document.getElementById("flash").contentDocument.close();
        window.frames[0].stop();
        window.frames[0].document.execCommand('Stop');
        $("#hideflash").hide();
    }
    if (!Modernizr.flash) {
        // Flash is not supported
        document.getElementById("flash").contentDocument.close();
        window.frames[0].stop();
        window.frames[0].document.execCommand('Stop');
        $("#hideflash").hide();
    }
</script>
```

I use a Modernizr custom script to determine whether the browser is Firefox or Supports Flash. If none of this is true I unload the HTML5 Player and the flash iframe comes up as planned. If however Firefox or lack of Flash support is detected I hide the iframe and initiate the HTML5 Player.

This is a pretty problematic setup but this is the only way to meet my company's demands. The main issue is that the code for stopping the iframe from loading sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't.

Any suggestions on this tricky one?

Comment: I would like to know if my code worked. Did the answer help?

Answer (score 4):

As Patrick said you can use flash as a fallback.  By using  the video tag you can speed up the load time of the website (not the video). You could use the following

```
<div class="hidden_element" id="hideflash">
    <iframe frameBorder="0" width="315" height="45" id="flash" scrolling="no" src="THESOURCE"></iframe>
</div>
<video src="video.ogv" controls>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Flash is not supported
        document.getElementById("flash").contentDocument.close();
        window.frames[0].stop();
        window.frames[0].document.execCommand('Stop');
        $("#hideflash").hide();
    </script>
</video>
```

You will want to test this and adjust as needed.
For more info use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Fallback_options), [this](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody), or [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/video-for-everybody-html5-video-with-flash-fallback/) website they each have a little different way to do it depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flash as a fallback with the `video` tag since browsers that can't support the `video` tag will ignore the opening and closing `video` tags and read the html that's in between. No need to use Modernizr.

```
<video src="video.ogv" controls>
    <object data="flvplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <param value="flvplayer.swf" name="movie"/>
    </object>
</video>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Fallback_options